# show that if $ n^2 +2$ and $ n^2-2$ are both primes then $3|n$

Tags: number-theory

show that if $n^2 +2 $ and $n^2-2$ are both primes then $3|n$. I don't think I have a clue to start this question

Comment: All prime numbers greater than 3 must equal $6k\pm 1$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Each $n$ can be written as $n=3k$ or $n=3k+1$ or $n=3k+2$ for some integer $k$.

Show that in the former 2 cases, $n^2+2$ OR $n^2-2$ is divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 0):

$3$ is prime.

By Fermat's Little Theorem, $3|a^3-a$.  Therefore $3|a^3-a-3a=a^3-4a=a(a-2)(a+2).$

Substituting $a=n^2,$ we have $3|n^2-2, n^2+2, $ or $n^2$.

If $n^2-2$ and $n^2+2$ are prime, this means $3|n^2$, which means $3|n$.

Comment: could also have said $3|a-1, a, $ or $ a+1,$ so $3|(a-1)a(a+1)=a^3-a$